# POST array along with other variable

Tags: php

I am doing a POST to pass checkbox group values using an array. Is it possible to pass another variable that I'm pulling from database and append it into this array? Or are there other ways to pass this particular value along with the array?

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='".$checkedIncident."' value='".$incidentID."'/></td></tr>";
```

This is the array i'm passing to another php on submit. I wish to pass another variable `$id` too.

Comment: What is `$checkedIncident`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hidden input. Assuming `$checkedIncident` is something like `incident[]` that is creating an array:

```
<input type="hidden" name="$checkedIncident" value="$id">
```